# Terminate running EC2 instance not used for long

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I terminate a running EC2 instance has not been used for a given period?

How can I check if the EC2 instance is being used or not before terminating?

Comment: How do you define "being used"?

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part of your requirement is to identify **whether an Amazon EC2 instance is "being used"**.

Amazon EC2 cannot see "inside" the instance, so it does not know whether anybody is logged in, or any processes that are running. You could use *CPU Utilization* to determine whether it is "being used", but that is not a reliable measure unless usage always involves significant CPU usage.

Alternatively, you could put a script on the EC2 instance that is triggered every few minutes by cron. The script could measure something that indicates "use", such as the number of logged-in users, or perhaps whether a particular process is running.

If you were able to determine whether it is "in use", you could send data to an **Amazon CloudWatch metric** (eg either a boolean to say it is in-use, or a measure such as the number of users). You could then create an **Amazon CloudWatch alarm** to trigger after a period of time if the measure is below a desired threshold. The alarm could then Terminate the instance.